# RecyclerView Item Not Shown when the item height is bigger than the height of the recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I use recyclerView with LinearLayoutManager.

When I try to show an item with a height bigger than the height of the recyclerView, I have an empty view.

I fix the height of the item below the height of the screen every things works, but when I use a fixed height like 900dp on item, I have an empty space.

Comment: Can you include the XML files and Adapter class

Comment: don't use fixed height, use wrap_content for height of your item. It will automatically detects the child height and wrap the parent as per height.

Comment: I use wrap_content but in some case the text is longuer and excceed the height of the screen.
In that case the layout will not be rendered and I have an empty space.

Comment: Add your codes to question... your question is not clear